# cut table name from query

Tags: sql, database, unix, sed, grep

i want to know how to cut `table` or `tables name(s)` from a query (select as example ) using unix commands

```
select c1, c2 from table.table1 ,table.table2
```

i know i can using `grep` or `sed`

please need your help

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd like to give a comment on SQL. Your example uses a very old syntax (tables comma-separated). The up-to-date syntax would use `table1 CROSS JOIN table2` for your example (or some other form of join, such as INNER JOIN for other queries). Given that some SQL dialects even allow for comments (e.g. `CROSS JOIN table2 /* CROSS JOIN desired here */`), parsing may become somewhat difficult.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "cut table names from a query".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it will help for you,

```
echo "select c1, c2 from table.table1 ,table.table2" | sed -r 's/.*from (.*),([^ ]+).*/\1\2/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean to using short name instead of full long table name? how about this:
    select t.columnname from longname t

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you are asking.  You should provide a sample where you have a sample input (as you provided) as well as a sample output.  You could use this simple sed command `sed 's/table\.//g'` if you are looking to get rid of the word `table`followed by the `.`. Notice that the `.` is escaped.

Cheers

Comment: i want to pars table names only from the query after loading the query to file

Comment: what is your desired output? Please edit your question and include that